# IF failure on string comparison within a FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64

I have been trying to follow some example I have found here and on other pages, but I can't manage to get the IF to work.

What I want to do is:

There is a file called `SIS134F160107.txt`. It has records of data with numbers.
I need to copy the lines that start with 09 (only) to another file which I can name `output.txt` or anything else.

My code is the following:

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "Comp=09"
FOR /F %%# IN (SIS134F160107.txt) DO (
    Call Set "Line=%%#"
    Call Echo %%Line%%
    Call Set "Token=%%Line%%"
    Call Echo %%Token%%
    Call Set "T=%%Token:~0,2%%"
    Call Echo %%T%%
    Call Echo %%Comp%%
    if %%T%%==%Comp% (call Echo Imprimir .%Comp%. .%%T%%.)
PAUSE
)
```

The result of this is that the IF does not print any information ever, but if I print the NOT statement of the IF I get:

```
C:\....\Batch>setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
C:\....\Batch>set "Comp=09"
C:\....\Batch>FOR /F %# IN (SIS134F160107.txt)
DO (
Call Set "Line=%#"
 Call Echo %Line%
 Call Set "Token=%Line%"
 Call Echo %Token%
 Call Set "T=%Token:~0,2%"
 Call Echo %T%
 Call Echo %Comp%
 if NOT %T% == 09 (call Echo Imprimir .09. .%T%. )
 PAUSE
)

C:\....\Batch>(
Call Set "Line=09Linea01"
 Call Echo %Line%
 Call Set "Token=%Line%"
 Call Echo %Token%
 Call Set "T=%Token:~0,2%"
 Call Echo %T%
 Call Echo %Comp%
 if NOT %T% == 09 (call Echo Imprimir .09. .%T%. )
 PAUSE
)
09Linea01
09Linea01
09
09
Imprimir .09. .09.
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\....\Batch>(
Call Set "Line=88Linea01"
 Call Echo %Line%
 Call Set "Token=%Line%"
 Call Echo %Token%
 Call Set "T=%Token:~0,2%"
 Call Echo %T%
 Call Echo %Comp%
 if NOT %T% == 09 (call Echo Imprimir .09. .%T%. )
 PAUSE
)
88Linea01
88Linea01
88
09
Imprimir .09. .88.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Some of the echos get 09 09 and some don't. So I don't understand why the IF is not working even when the strings are "Equal".

I have tried to use EQU as well but its no use.

Where is the mistake in my code resulting in a string comparison not working as expected by me?

Comment: To get just the lines that start with 09, you may use this: `findstr /B "09" SIS134F160107.txt > anotherFile.txt`

Comment: it's afternoon in my place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix your code, but there is a much better way. This is exactly the type of problem that FINDSTR is designed to solve.

The solution becomes a simple one liner using a simple regular expression search:

```
findstr "^09" "SIS134F160107.txt" >output.txt
```

Or this one liner using a string literal search

```
findstr /b /c:"09" "SIS134F160107.txt" >output.txt
```

Comment: GOD! its my first time on this kind of coding, i didnt knew i could use findstr like that!!!! it worked on my test_batch, now i'll have to get the Path and file name from predefined formats and it will be done. Thanks for the Help all of help!

Answer (score 0):

For starters... the leading 0 in 09 makes it assume that the number is octal. 09 is not a legal octal number. Do a string compare instead of an arithmetic compare. Change all occurrences of

```
if NOT %T% == 09
```

to

```
if NOT "%T%"=="09"
```

Comment: This is true, i tryed to compare and it said it was an octal number thus not valid. I went back to code and used the "%comp%" value for the compare instead of using the 09 directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have invoked `delayedexpansion`, there is no need to `call echo ...`. `echo !line!` or `echo !token!` will work just as well. `%var%` extracts the "at the time of parsing" value of `var` and `!var!` the "currrent value as changed by running" value.

```
if %%T%%==%Comp%
```

Would be interpreted as

if "%T%"=="*the original value of comp*"

and hence unless `comp` contains the literal value `%T%` then the result will be false; hence not-this is true.

Use

```
if "!T!"=="%comp%" ....
```

which compares the **current** value of `T` to the **original** value of `comp`.

Comment: Hi, I used this compare and the IF statement worked. Thanks for the Help!